# Asp.net 5 web api bearer authentication and multiple areas

Tags: authentication, asp.net-web-api, jwt, bearer-token, asp.net5

I have a webapi backend that several client applications are using. The api is secured with jwt authentication, it is based upon the following example: https://github.com/mrsheepuk/ASPNETSelfCreatedTokenAuthExample. Since I am not yet very comfortable with all the concepts of token based authentication I could use some guidance in this. My issue is that I need my applications to utilize the same api but to limit access for each application to a specific area or controller.

According to the example I can protect methods within an area with:

```
[Authorize("Api")]
```

A policy is added in startup with

```
    authOptions.AddPolicy("Api", new AuthorizationPolicyBuilder()
        .AddAuthenticationSchemes(JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme) // "Bearer" scheme
        .RequireAuthenticatedUser().Build());
```

For secured requests from the client I typically have an angular 2 app that simply adds the jwt in the headers like so:

```
headers.append('Authorization', 'Bearer ' + jwt);
```

I don't know of all the mechanics here but I am assuming that when a secure method is requested, the "Api" attribute decoration is what decides/limits which policy is to be used with a certain route in the api.

What is best practice and how do I extend this to work with individually accessible sections?

Answer (score 0):

You can create an `ActionFilterAttribute` for `Authorization` and use it on all the actions.

You can implement the `FrameworkAuthorise` filter methods as per your requirements.

[image]

`Global.ApiKey` is the unique code for your application to identity you have access to that application or not.

```
     [FrameworkAuthorise(Global.ApiKey, AuthorisationType.None)]
     public async Task<IHttpActionResult> Get()        
     { 
        // code goes here
     }

    [FrameworkAuthorise(Global.ApiKey, AuthorisationType.Bearer)]
     public async Task<IHttpActionResult> Post()        
     { 
        // code goes here
     }
```

---

Comment: Thank you Venky, I will see if I can get a sense of this and make it work with my project.